# Consume asmx service With Wcf Client?

Tags: wcf

I have an old asmx service on the air. ( Not Myne)

I want to consume it by wcf.

And i want to do it by the traditional way ( ABC)

A = I have.

B = Simple http Binding ( old asmx)

C = **XXX** ??? //<-- how do i get the Contract ? SVCUTIL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> B = Simple http Binding ( old asmx)

It will be [basicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.aspx).

> C = XXX ??? //<-- how do i get the Contract ? SVCUTIL ?

Yes, you use [`svcutil.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx) or the [Add Service Reference dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386382.aspx) in Visual Studio to generate a strongly typed proxy from the WSDL of the asmx service:

```
svcutil.exe http://example.com/legacy.asmx?WSDL
```

svcutil.exe will also generate an app.config file for you containing the `<client>` section with the correct endpoint to be used to consume the service.