# How to call an asmx service which needs authorization from WCF in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, .net-3.5

How can I call an asmx service which needs windows identity authorization from WCF in .NET 3.5? We are limited to .NET 3.5 framework. I have the credentials, but not sure how to implement this in C# code.

Comment: What do you mean by "authenticated"? Do you mean that the service is only accessed using SSL, or that it requires Windows authentication to access?

Comment: Probably a duplicate off http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860966/consume-asmx-service-with-wcf-client

Comment: @nateirvin it needs windows authentication which i have.But not sure how to call using WCF

Comment: @ArturUdod this is not a duplicate.Here i ask about WCF calling a asmx which needs windows credentials which i have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example of authentication at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406125 In this url this is done as follows:

```
public decimal ReportSales()
{
    var currentUser = new WindowsPrincipal((WindowsIdentity)
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity);
    if (currentUser.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.BackupOperator))
    {
        return 10000M;
    }
    else
    {
       return -1M;
    }
 }
```

There are also alternative methods with compiler attributes described in http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/19/implementing-an-authorization-attribute-for-wcf-web-api.aspx

For later versions of .net WIF would be the way to go.

I hope this helps...